# Why are CSS horizontal margins uneven in this simple case, if specified explicitly?

Tags: html, css

Consider this simple example:

```htm
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.testbtnholder {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  height: calc(100% - 2.5em);
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  margin: 0 1em;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>Test</div>
  <div class="testbtnholder">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I'd like the left and right margins to be 1 em - but for some reason, they are not equal; the below is a Firefox 50 screenshot, imported in Inkscape, where I've drawn some lines along the margins, and used the Extensions / Visualize Path / Measure Path ...:

[image: f1a]

So Firefox tells me under Computed Box Model that my margins are 16 px, but in actuality the left one is about 24 px, and the right one is about 5 px smaller than the left.

But, if I comment `/* margin: 0 1em; */`, and I uncomment `margin: 0 auto;` in the example, then for some reason, the left/right margins are equal ?!:

[image: f2a]

... however, then the Computed Box Model is not helpful at all, as it just tells me "auto" for the margins - measuring in Inkscape it turns out they're both around 21 px ?!

So, how can I specify `margin-right` and `margin-left` to an explicit number (in px, em etc), AND have them be rendered as equal - as if I've specified `auto` margins? EDIT: and can anyone explain why do the margins look different in my first case?

Comment: 24px in the 1st case might come from 16px margin of the element itself plus 8px default margin of the `body` element. And the extra 4px of width likely comes from the 2px border because `box-sizing` is `content-box` by default.

Comment: Thanks @IlyaStreltsyn - Re: "... plus 8px default margin of the body element." - but am I not already using `html, body {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}`? Why is that not honored? Thanks for the  `box-sizing` comment, that makes sense to me ....

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. In JSfiddle your code works in Firefox 50 as expected, with no default body margin: https://jsfiddle.net/j630oxfh/. Aren't there in your original code any invisible characters before the first selector that may accidentally be parsed as a part of the selector, making it ivalid?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - no invisible characters... I think the problem is two-fold: one, the `box-sizing` which you mentioned; another that I don't need to specify both child width, and left+right margin width - but by now, I cannot really formulate this clearly, I'll have to come back to this another day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removing the width property on `.testbtnholder` and just set the margin would work

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.testbtnholder{
  margin: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgvfeffr/1/

In other words: simplify your css and remove properties that you don't need

Comment: Thanks @MattiaNocerino - could you explain why I should remove the `width` property in this case?

Comment: Because it's a `div`, a `block-element`. It's going to take all the width possible as default, because that's the standard behaviour of a `block-element!`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp.

Comment: Thanks @MattiaNocerino - it makes sense; but why would there be a problem, if I explicitly say the width is `calc(100% - 2em)`, whereas the margins should be `1em` each, which should in the end add up to 100%?

Comment: If you want to set margins width the width property (i  don't know why you would do it btw) check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgvfeffr/7/

(if you want more explanation of this i can update the answer, just ask if you need)

Comment: Hm, I guess I get it know - are you trying to say that specifying both the width and the margins (in case they are equal) are mutually exclusive, because there already is a limitation on the total width from the parent? I.e. if I have parent width of 100%, and child width 80%, then equal-sized margins for child are already specified as (100%-80%)/2; likewise, if parent is 100%, and I specify equal-sized margins of 1em, that in itself specifies the child width as (100%-2*1em)?

Comment: Wow, that gave me some headache! Ahaha :P. Anyway, yes. If you set a child width 80% and you center it, of course it's going to have a margin of 10% and 10% by its sides. If you don't center the element, there's going to be all the 20% on the right side. Same if you just set its margin... being a block element, it's going to be 100% width minus the margin you specified. If you center it, the margins are going to be equal on both sides, if you don't center it, it's going to be only on the right side. I hope it's clear now :P

Comment: @sdbbs i hate to remind it but you still haven't accepted an answer!

Comment: His @MattiaNocerino - well, none of the answers completely answer my query, most of the stuff I learned is in comments. If I ever have time, I will make another answer  summarizing what I think is important and accept that, but for now I've accepted yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can have in contained inside another div and give this new div padding of your desire.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.testbtncontain {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:2em 2.5em;
}
.testbtnholder {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>Test</div>
  <div class="testbtncontain">
  <div class="testbtnholder">
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @AtulBishnoi  - could you explain why do I need a container, and cannot just use the div directly as I did?

Comment: The container is used to provide a proper width for the layout, acting as a wrapper for the content. it doesn't let it flow and avoids confusion for browser

Comment: in your case when you gave  width: calc(100% - 2em);  and  margin: 0 1em; the browser got confused and made both margins unequal

Comment: The same kind of thing happen when someone uses  '!important' property too much.

Comment: Thanks @AtulBishnoi - I see what you're saying, but there must be a better explanation than "the browser got confused" - there must be some influence from the order of calculations or something, otherwise I don't see why `calc(100% - 2em);` and `margin: 0 1em;` would interfere ?!

Comment: when you set its width by calc(100% - 2em);  it sets it's width and gives some margin. then again when you say  calc(100% - 2em);  then it has to update those margins, and whichever is greater wins the race

Comment: you see, 'em' is a relative measure. 2em in first case is not equal to 1em+1em in second case

Comment: Thanks @AtulBishnoi - I was unaware that setting a width automatically calculates margins too, but if that is the case, "*whichever is greater wins the race*" does make sense. But, I disagree that "*2em in first case is not equal to 1em+1em in second case*"; `em` is relative to the font size of the parent; so if the parent has font size of 16 px, then 1 em is 16px, 2em is 32 px etc, and since all of my `em`s are in the `.testbtnholder` element, there is no reason they should differ between each other.

Comment: when you set the width , the 'em' used here takes reference of the body (container of your div) but when you set the margins in the next lines 'em' used here takes reference of your div.

Comment: All of the answers & comments here revealed a piece of the puzzle @AtulBishnoi, so right now I am in doubt what to accept - I think the best will be to leave this for a couple of days, and then come back to it and decide what to accept...

Answer (score 1):

use box-sizing property and add padding , try with this snippet

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    .testbtncontain {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding:2em 2.5em;
    }
    .testbtnholder {
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid gray;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div class="testbtncontain">
 <div class="testbtnholder"></div>
</div>
```

or you can use this snippet also decrease the `width` and set `margin:0 auto;`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.testbtnholder {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div class="testbtnholder"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @JishnuVS - I have already realized `margin:0 auto;` works; what I'm wondering about, is why doesn't explicit margin in units work, when I'm specifying the width explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

IlyaStreltsyn is right, you just need to add box-sizing:border-box to .testbtnholder and that's it, you get 2 equals margins

```
.testbtnholder{
display: block;
border: 2px solid gray;
width: calc(100% - 2em);
height: calc(100% - 2.5em);
margin: 0 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```